# What is the difference between instancesRespondToSelector and respondsToSelector in Objective-C?

Tags: objective-c

The only difference I observed on my own is that `respondsToSelector`'s receiver can either be a class or an instance, while `instancesRespondToSelector` can only have a class receiver. What else makes them different, though? Are there any performance issues with one or the other?

Comment: respondsToSelector's receiver can only be an instance object. instancesRespondToSelector's receiver can only be a Class object. The + or - does make a difference in the type of method

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Under the hood, `-[NSObject respondsToSelector:]` is implemented like this:

```
- (BOOL)respondsToSelector:(SEL)aSelector {
    return class_respondsToSelector([self class], aSelector);
}
```

and `+[Class instancesRespondToSelector:]` is implemented like this:

```
+ (BOOL)instancesRespondToSelector:(SEL)aSelector {
    return class_respondsToSelector(self, aSelector);
}
```

(I used [Hopper](http://www.hopperapp.com/) on CoreFoundation to figure this out.)

So, there's basically no difference.  However, you can override `respondsToSelector:` in your own class to return YES or NO on a per-instance basis (`NSProxy` does this).  You can't do that with `instancesRespondToSelector:`.

Comment: Little remark, `instancesRespondToSelector:` **can** (and **must**, if you implement message forwarding mechanism) be override. See [Objective-C Runtime Programming Guide, section Forwarding and Inheritance](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjCRuntimeGuide/Articles/ocrtForwarding.html)

Comment: @rob_mayoff I totally know what you are saying here, but just a small point: in your first statement you have [NSObject respondsToSelector:], but NSObject is itself a class name so it confused for a bit. You meant NSObjectInstance right?

Comment: It is common to write `-[NSObject respondsToSelector:]` when referring to an instance message defined by the `NSObject` class (that is, a message that can be sent to any instance of `NSObject` or its subclasses).  We write `+[NSObject instancesRespondToSelector:]` to refer to a class message defined by the `NSObject` class.

Answer (score 9):

One difference is `respondsToSelector` can't tell you if an instance inherits a method from its superclass, so if you want to do something like `[super respondsToSelector:_cmd];` it wont work, you need to to `[[self superclass] instancesRespondToSelector:_cmd];`

Comment: Hm, okay. But isn't that more because of Objective-C's inheritance semantics, not really a difference between the two methods? Because if I'm not mistaken, by your example, `[[self superclass] respondsToSelector:_cmd];` would work.

Comment: no, because there is no method on Class called respondsToSelector:. respondsToSelector is part of the NSObject protocol, which Class doesnt conform to

Comment: @wattson12 `NSObject` and its subclasses respond to the class method `+respondsToSelector:`.

Comment: is that actually a class method or is it responding to its own instance method? i couldnt find a +respondsToSelector: in the docs?

Answer (score 4):

`respondsToSelector:` is an *instance* method and determines whether an object, which could be an instance of a class *or* a class object, responds to a selector. When you pass a instance you are testing for an instance method, when you pass a class object you are testing for a class method.

`instancesRespondToSelector:` is a *class* method and determines if instances of a class respond to a selector. It allows testing for an instance method given a class and *without* having an instance of that class.