# Checking for availability of iOS classes (rather than methods) in MonoTouch

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, weak-linking

MonoTouch exposes the [RespondsToSelector](http://iosapi.xamarin.com/?link=M:MonoTouch.Foundation.NSObject.RespondsToSelector%28MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Selector%29) method for checking the availability of methods across iOS versions.

However I can't seem to find out how to perform the similar checks for class availability.
[Apple documents it here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/cross_development/Using/using.html) that in iOS 4.2+ you should attempt to access a static `class` selector of the required class. e.g:

```
if ([EKReminder class]) 
{
    ....
}
```

However that doesn't seem to be exposed. I think it is similar to [my previous question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14534509), in that to implement this in MT it would need explicit mapping of a `Class` static property on every MT type.

So I guess my question is, should I just use the old pre iOS 4.2 technique? i.e:

```
Class cls = NSClassFromString (@"EKReminder");
if (cls) 
{
    ...
}
```

Which I think maps to:

```
var iosClass = Class.GetHandle("EKReminder");
if ( iosClass != null )
    ...
```

Or call the selector manually using the interop methods available in [Messaging](http://docs.go-mono.com/?link=T:MonoTouch.ObjCRuntime.Messaging)?

Or some other approach that I havn't found?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The *safe* check is using:

```
if (Class.GetHandle (typeof (EKReminder)) != IntPtr.Zero) {
    // we know we can use EKReminder
}
```

However it's a bit costly because it involves reflection. The Objective-C name can differ from the .NET name (e.g. `NSURL` versus `NSUrl` and that can only be found by reflecting the `Register` attribute).

If you know the Objective-C name then you can use the, non-type safe, overload to skip reflection. E.g.

```
// checking for NSUrl would not work
if (Class.GetHandle ("NSURL") != IntPtr.Zero) {
    // we know we can use NSUrl
}
```

Again (and to generalize my answer for everyone) it's often best/easier/faster to use the iOS version to do runtime checks for non-hardware features.

```
if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion (5,0)) {
    // we know feature X was added in 5.0
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just use the pre-iOS 4.2 technique:

```
var iosClass = Class.GetHandle ("EKReminder");
if (iOSClass != null)
    ...
```

The method recommended by Apple seems to be special-cased by gcc/clang, which will not work in MonoTouch.