# How to use [NSObject instancesRespondToSelector]

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm uncertain how to use this method, I've tried code below and assumed that both should return YES, but I'm observing something different. Can somebody please explain? [UILocalNotification setRegion:] is new in iOS8.

```
BOOL test0 = [[[UILocalNotification alloc] init] respondsToSelector:@selector(setRegion:)];
BOOL test1 = [UILocalNotification instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(setRegion:)];
```

debug window shows test values to be:

```
test0 = (BOOL)YES;
test1 = (BOOL)NO;
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [What is the difference between instancesRespondToSelector and respondsToSelector in Objective-C?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11574478/what-is-the-difference-between-instancesrespondtoselector-and-respondstoselector)

Comment: you're not `init`-ing after you allocate in the second, which explains the `NO`. If you don't have an instance, it couldn't respond to a selector.

Comment: instancesRespondToSelector is a class method (signature is: +instancesRespondToSelector:), according to Apple: Returns a Boolean value that indicates whether instances of the receiver are capable of responding to a given selector.

Comment: @Todd, he's not allocating in the second call, he's using a class method that returns a bool, therefore, he doesn't need to alloc-init.

Comment: See the second answer in the question Rick linked to: [2nd SO Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11574745/451475) by wattson12.

Comment: lol. My sleep deprivation is starting to show. Upvote.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Whilst understanding that one is a class method, and the other an instance method, I couldn't understand how (or why) the two would return different answers.  To add to the confusion, if I do

```
BOOL test2 = [[[[UILocalNotification alloc] init] class] instancesRespondToSelector:@selector(setRegion:)];
```

then the answer is YES!  So I checked, and if you look at the class for the object returned by alloc init, it is different:

```
UILocalNotification *local = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];
NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromClass([local class]));
NSLog(@"%@", NSStringFromClass([UILocalNotification class]));
```

returns:

```
2014-11-14 12:48:14.990 Test[6750:22555] UIConcreteLocalNotification
2014-11-14 12:48:14.991 Test[6750:22555] UILocalNotification
```

Which explains how come the answers are different.

Comment: Good answer, it makes sense now. Although it would be nice if docs mention that UILocalNotification is just an interface. Thanks.

Comment: Agreed regarding the docs.  I couldn't see anything in the UILocalNotification.h either.